# How do I pass parameters from xrdp to the vnc viewer such as viewonly?

Tags: vnc, xrdp, vncviewer, rdp

**Goal**:

To use **xrdp** as a proxy to view VNC connections from another ip address, while passing parameters to the vncviewer.

Everything works except passing the `-viewonly` switch to the vncserver that is running NOT on the xrdp host, but another pc running VNC server.

- Vnc server is running on WinXP and Win7.
- Xrdp is running on Ubuntu14 server with LXDE booting to console.
- The RDP client is Win7 and Win10.

Xrdp currently works on the local host using sesman and xorgxrdp.

Xrdp currently works as a proxy to the WinXP vncserver, but I am unable to pass switches or parameters to the vncviewer.

xrdp was compiled from [git](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp).

Configured with --enable-painter to allow a Win10 client and --enable-fuse for drive redirection.

```
./configure --enable-painter --enable-fuse
```

xorgxrdp was compiled from [git](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xorgxrdp).

Configured without any switches

```
./configure
```

This should not matter as it deals with the localhost X server and not the proxy vnc server.

Relevant section of the xrdp.ini file:

```
[rep7]
name=rep7
lib=libvnc.so
username=na
password=ask
ip=rep7
port=5900
```

This does work, but the vnc connection is read/write.
I could set a separate view only password, but would like to avoid that because there are many computers to deal with.

I can run from the command line `vncviewer -viewonly rep7`.

I need to pass the viewonly switch via the xrdp.ini or other file.

**What I have done so far**:

The *sesman.ini* file has a `key=value` pair named `param`. I did try this in the *xrdp.ini* file with no luck.

```
param=-viewonly
```

I have replaced the `lib=libvnc.so` with `lib=vncviewer -viewonly` also quoted it `lib='vncviewer -viewonly'`.

also

```
lib=vncviewer
param=-viewonly
```